# c# dataGridView in Menu hide then show using other form called frmDriver after close show the dataGridViewMenu

Tags: c#, datagridview

This is my menu form, I have a datagridView in my menu and I hide this but did not show the datagridview in next form called frmDriver on closing function.

```
    private void paymentToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmDriver tForm = new frmDriver();
        tForm.MdiParent = this;
        tForm.Text = "Payment Transaction " + childFormNumber++;
        tForm.Show();
        dataGridViewMenu.Visible = false;
    }
```

This is the next form called **frmDriver**. But didn't show the datagridviewMenu in my frmMenu after I close this frmDriver. Help me please...

```
    private void frmDriver_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        frmMenu.dataGridViewMenu.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: might be frmMenu is null in frmDriver_FormClosing.Can you check once.

Comment: how to use this null in frmDriver? I try it but have a error. My purpose for this datagridview is to hide if click the menu item like form Driver then show form Driver to the MDI Parent and if I close the form Driver show the datagridview in the MDI Parent. Please I need help more help because this is my project.